# Contact Form 7 "non-selectable" options in a drop down

Tags: plugins, forms, dropdown, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I'm using CF7 and I need to have a dropdown with a non selectable category "header"
such as

**US States**

AL

AK

AR...etc.

**Countries**

Afganistan

Albania etc....

With "US States" and "Countries" not an option to submit.
Thanks
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/[1]

EDIT: I solved the problem myself if anyone has the same issue

I used JQuery and gave the options I wanted to make non-selectable an empty value.

```
$("option:nth-child(1), option:nth-child(1)").val("");
$("option:nth-child(1), option:nth-child(53)").val("");
 });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how your solution works, but there is a semantic element created for exactly what you want: [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup). Whatever your solution, I'd encourage you to use that instead.

Searching for "contact form 7 optgroup" you'll discover that other people are looking for the same thing you are and trying to implement `<optgroup>` to do it. [Here's one answer](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-optgroup-in-a-drop-down-menu?replies=9) that includes both a javascript solution and a plugin hack (probably not a good idea). Probably the better solution I've found is [this one](http://www.codeillustrator.com/2012/08/optgroups-within-contact-form-7-in.html). It's a javascript to replace Contact Form 7 select options with the optgroup element using a specified syntax.

That final solution should probably remain stable even if CF7 adds optgroup support down the road.